# What is a Template Input File? (in the FIM Synchronisation Service)

Tags: active-directory, extensibility, dsml

I have been trying to create an extended management agent in the Synchronization Service Manager. I go through the wizard, select an 'Extensible Connectivity', pick the dll file that I have just created using 'Create Extension Projects' and, moving along, I get to the infamous 'Select Template Input File' section.

There, I am forced to pick a Template Input File and am offered a number of File Formats (AVP, Delimited, DSML, Fixed and LDIF). However, I have no idea what any of those files are meant to look like - I have tried a dsml file (that I got somewhere on the net, but I get a 'Failed to Parse the template input file' error message).

Can a sample be provided?

What I am trying to do:

I want to know when users change their name, surname, email and ad group from an AD Server, and then call a web service to relay the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be building an ECMA on top of the ECMA v2 framework which doesn't require these files.

If you want to build a legacy ECMA for some reason, delimited is a simple delimited file - line 1 should be your column names (e.g. ID|FirstName|Surname|Email) and subsequent rows should be data. You only need one row of data to get past this step (e.g. 1|Brian|Desmond|brian@contoso.com).

Comment: Yep, figured this out in the end... it was just weird to have to pass a sample data file when you are essentially asked to provide the template of how that data file should look like.